# How do I get a user profile's picture from entity_metadata_wrapper()?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I am using `entity_metadata_wrapper()` for getting values from the user profile.

This is my code:

```
$user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $uid);
$user_name = $user_wrapper->name->value();
```

How do I get the user picture field from `$user_wrapper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information about user picture *indirectly* as follows:

```
$user_picture = $user_wrapper->value()->picture;
```

I said *indirectly*, since the picture object itself is not an entity wrapper anymore, so you cannot chain it further using `entity_metadata_wrapper` functions. However, it should have all the information you need about the user picture, like the `fid`, `filename`, `uri`, `filemime`, `filesize`, `metadata`, and any other fields that could be attached to a file, for instance using File Entity module.

Comment: If you want it wrapped, you need to apply this patch I proposed a while back: https://www.drupal.org/node/2224645